# move file from one location to another in putty

Tags: bash, putty

i have created folder on my server (ie finesse)- 'home' in which i have several `perl(.pl)` files as

tt.pl, re.pl etc.

now i have created new folder in 'home' folder called 'perl'

and want to move tt.pl and re.pl in perl folder

is there any command to do so (like cut-paste in windows)?

note: i am using putty 0.60 on windows xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

`mv - move (rename) files`

```
   mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
   mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
   mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

In your case:

`mv tt.pl re.pl perl/`

Answer (score 0):

mv home/*.pl home/perl/

Is that what you are looking for?